# Non-linear interpolation of a range to another range

Tags: javascript

I'm struggling with creating a function, that interpolates one range to another. I already have a functioning linear interpolation, but getting more 'curved' interpolations, I am stumped.

F.ex. I want to interpolate the range `[0,100]` to `[0,1000]` in a way, so target-values near 0 is more likely than target-values near 1000 (or vice-versa).

One approach I got working was using logarithmic interpolation, which has some annoying drawbacks:

- I used a crude hack to deal with negative numbers (f.ex. [-70,50]), by offsetting the range before calculating
- The 'slope' is not adjustable (f.ex. if I want the target-value to be just a bit more likely or a lot more likely than a linear interpolation)

> function logPol (value, s1, s2, t1, t2) {
>
> ```
> var f = (value - s1) / ((value - s1) + (s2 - value));
> var add = 0;
>
> if(t1 <= 0 || t2 <= 0) {
>     add = t1 >= t2? 2 * Math.abs(t2) + 1 : 2 * Math.abs(t1) + 1;
>
>     t1 += add;
>     t2 += add;
> }
>
> var interpolated = Math.pow(t2,f) * Math.pow(t1, 1-f) - add;
>
>
> return interpolated;
> ```
>
> };

I've read a lot of articles on quadratic equations, thinking that would solve my problem, but never ended up with a working solution. If I need to explain something further, please let me know.

Comment: You're not looking for an interpolation, but for a mapping?

Comment: If you do not know how to do the math, you are in the wrong spot, since it has absolutely nothing to do with programming in JavaScript (or any other language).

Comment: You should look at d3, which does everything you want and more.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After reading a ton of different approaches, I finally solved my problem, and ended up using Bezier curves to handle my interpolation. Here's my resulting function:

```
    /**
 * Returns a bezier interpolated value, using the given ranges
 * @param {number} value  Value to be interpolated
 * @param {number} s1 Source range start
 * @param {number} s2  Source range end
 * @param {number} t1  Target range start
 * @param {number} t2  Target range end
 * @param {number} [slope]  Weight of the curve (0.5 = linear, 0.1 = weighted near target start, 0.9 = weighted near target end)
 * @returns {number} Interpolated value
 */
var interpolate = function (value, s1, s2, t1, t2, slope) {
    //Default to linear interpolation
    slope = slope || 0.5;

    //If the value is out of the source range, floor to min/max target values
    if(value < Math.min(s1, s2)) {
        return Math.min(s1, s2) === s1 ? t1 : t2;
    }

    if(value > Math.max(s1, s2)) {
        return Math.max(s1, s2) === s1 ? t1 : t2;
    }

    //Reverse the value, to make it correspond to the target range (this is a side-effect of the bezier calculation)
    value = s2-value;

    var C1 = {x: s1, y:t1}; //Start of bezier curve
    var C3 = {x: s2, y:t2}; //End of bezier curve
    var C2 = {              //Control point
        x: C3.x,
        y: C1.y + Math.abs(slope) * (C3.y - C1.y)
    };

    //Find out how far the value is on the curve
    var percent = value / (C3.x-C1.x);

    return C1.y*b1(percent) + C2.y*b2(percent) + C3.y*b3(percent);

    function b1(t) { return t*t }
    function b2(t) { return 2*t*(1 - t)  }
    function b3(t) { return (1 - t)*(1 - t) }
};
```